# ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

This is my function:

```
DECLARE
f_ids integer[] := '{}';
BEGIN
SELECT INTO f_ids  "fileId" FROM "tbFiles" WHERE "size" <= $2 AND
"size" >=$1 ;
RETURN f_ids;
END;
```

This function should return `bigint[]`, but when I try to run it I get this error:

```
SELECT "GetFilesBySize"(0,888)

ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "GetFilesBySize" line 4 at SQL statement
```

It seems to me that the array is properly initialized, so where is the mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work:

```
DECLARE
    f_ids integer[];
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO f_ids array_agg(fileId) FROM tbFiles WHERE size <= $2 AND size >=$1;
    RETURN f_ids;
END
```

But I think, you are better off using real *set returning functions* or use `RETURN QUERY`. Lookup the PostgreSQL manual for the both terms.